# Creating and Appending to a Dictionary of Lists?

Tags: python

edit: the second link solved my problem, thank you!

I have a global variable "messages", my keys will be "channel" and my values will be "message"

I have tried:

```
messages = {}
if channel not in messages:
    messages[channel] = message
else:
    messages[channel].append(message)
```

and:

```
messages = {}
if channel not in messages:
    messages[channel][0] = message
else:
    messages[channel].append(message)
```

How do I create a new dictionary key and append values to it?

I'm sorry if this is a repeat question, I looked hard but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @coldspeed, that dupe is a stretch.

Comment: I was about to provide an answer but it is closed. I will provide it here. 
`messages = {};
if channel not in messages:
    messages[channel] = [message];
else:
    messages[channel].append(message)`  You simply need to enclose the initial message in `[]` for it to start the list

Comment: @StephenRauch Ah, thanks for adding the more accurate one!